# Alexander Duality With $\mathbb{R}^n$ Instead Of $S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

The Alexander Duality states:

> Let $K$ be a compact, locally contractible, nonempty, proper subspace of $S^n$. Then there is an isomorphism:
>   $$\tilde{H}_i(S^n\setminus K;R) \cong \tilde{H}^{n-i-1}(K;R)$$

Apparently, $\tilde{H}_i(S^n\setminus K;R) \cong \tilde{H}_i(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K;R)$, but I do not understand why or how to prove this. Does it have to do with excision?

Comment: I presume you want $\cdots \cong \tilde{H}^{n-i-1}(K;R)$ in your first equation?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. Let me fix that.

Comment: Your second equation is not true. If $K$ is a point then $S^n\setminus K$ is a disk but $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus K$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's not true in general. I was interested in the case $n = 2$ and $K \cong S^1$. How would one go about proving this then?

Comment: @FredericChopin For $S^1 \subset S^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ it's still not true. $S^2 \setminus S^1$ is two contractible components, but one of the two components of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to the circle.